# creating python package with multiple level of folders

Tags: python

I would like to create a package of my python code.
My folder structure is like below:

```
sing*(this is a folder)*
--ml*(this is a folder)*
----regression*(this is a folder)*
------linear.py*(this is a class file with functions in it)* 
----classification*(this is a folder)*
------logistic.py*(this is a class file with functions in it)*
```

i want to access class within linear.py by something like:

```
from sing.ml.regression import linear
```

Please advice how to create a package like this

thanks in advance

Comment: you already should be able to access to linear from where you are using absolute imports, I believe

Comment: my consumer application is hosted on azure.

Comment: @Shinratensei, are you saying that if i were to have a test.py file in "sing" folder then inside the test.py i can call linear.py class by saying "sing.ml.regression import linear" ?

Comment: from what I've read in other questions, yes, you should be able to

Comment: No i get the following error "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sing
    __init__.py
    -ml
        __init__.py
        -regression
           __init__.py
           linear.py

        -classification
           __init__.py
           logistic.py
```

And if the working directory of application is not parent folder of sing then you need to register folder 'sing' into PYTHONPATH environment variable.

For importing *linear* from sing folder you can use relative path:

```
from ml.regression import linear
```

and for calling function of linear file you can use:

```
linear.<*functionname*>(...)
```

Comment: error is "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" and the code is import os
os.chdir("/Users/Documents/sing");
from ml.regression import Linear

obj=Linear()

Comment: even if i try "linear.<*functionname*>(...)" and get the same error

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a `__init__.py` files in every folder, so that python interpret the other *.py files (and folder) as packages. A empty file is enough.