# How to create a Python package with multiple directories

Tags: python, github, module, package

There is a question like mine in the link below:

[creating python package with multiple level of folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025044/creating-python-package-with-multiple-level-of-folders)

However, after following the answers to the question and trying some other things that I thought might work I did not succeed.

I have created a working package with a number of functions here:

https://github.com/aaronengland/prestige

In the *prestige* directory is an ***init**.py* file containing some classes and functions. I have a class named `preprocessing` and I can call any of the functions from that class using:

`from prestige import preprocessing as pre`

And then (for example):

`pre.Binaritizer()`

However, I want to be able to import those functions using:

`import prestige.preprocessing as pre`

Using the first link (above) I was unsuccessful in doing this. I feel like it should be a simple solution, but for some reason I have not been able to get it to work. Can someone please show me how to make this possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Everything defined inside the `preprocessing` class should be moved to either a separate file called `preprocessing.py` or into a `__init__.py` file inside the subdirectory `preprocessing` which would be inside the main `prestige` source directory.  I would strongly recommend taking time to review the file organizational structure many open source Python projects out there such as [`django`](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django) or heck, [`scikit-learn`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) and take some hints from them.

Comment: @metatoaster I have been fiddling with that file structure in a sister package at *https://github.com/aaronengland/prestige_v2* but it has not worked for me yet. Is there anything in the ```setup.py``` file that needs to change when I have multiple directories?

Comment: You might be looking for instructions on building [namespace packages in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621131/python-namespace-packages-in-python3).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by organizing the file structure as follows:

> - prestige
> - setup.py
> - init.py
> - general.py
> - preprocessing.py

*setup.py* was set up [as I normally do](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html#adding-additional-files), *general.py* contains functions/classes, and *preprocessing.py* contains functions/classes. The *init.py* file contains 2 lines of code:

`from .preprocessing import *` and `from .general import *`

So, I did not create new directories, I just divided my functions into separate *.py* files and imported them into my *init.py* file.

Now, I am able to import functions using, for example:

`from prestige.preprocessing import Binaritizer`

Hopefully this helps someone in the future with a similar question.

The package can be accessed [here](https://github.com/aaronengland/prestige).